# Custom taxonomy template getting 404

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom taxonomy `Publications`. Which contains terms like `Marketing`, `Sales`.

The slug is set to be `/p/`. Code sample:

```
// Publication Taxonomy

function publication_taxonomy() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Publications', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Publication', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Publication', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Publications', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Publication', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Publication:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Publication Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Publication', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Publication', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Publication', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Publication', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate publication with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove publications', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular publications', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search publication', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    'no_terms'                   => __( 'No publications', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'                 => __( 'Publications list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Publications list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'rewrite'                                    => array( 'slug' => 'p' ),
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_in_rest'                       => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'publication', array( 'post','guide' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'publication_taxonomy', 0 );
```

The URL structures are working like this:

- example.com/p/marketing
- example.com/p/sales

Those load the template I've made `taxonomy-publication.php`

Now I'm trying to make a template that will render when I visit `example.com/p/` but all I'm getting is a 404.

I've tried refreshing the permalink settings, but can't understand why `/p/` won't load taxonomy-publication.php. Any ideas?